# Can't call controller by using urlRouterProvider Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I try to make this <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d1wwr3bPvWn3XFz4G7yJ?p=preview)</kbd> to work, spent more then 5 hours, posting here was a last resort.

**app.js**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
          .state('tab', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "tabs.html"
    })

    // the pet tab has its own child nav-view and history
    .state('tab.pet-index', {
      url: '/pets',
      views: {
        'pets-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'pet-index.html',
          controller: 'PetIndexCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('tab.pet-detail', {
      url: '/pet/:petId',
      views: {
        'pets-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'pet-detail.html',
          controller: 'PetDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    });

console.log('app load ...');

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/pets');

});
```

Here I call `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/pets')`

But I fail to get controller:

```
app.controller('PetIndexCtrl', function($scope, PetService) {
  console.log('PetIndexCtrl load ...');
  $scope.pets = PetService.all();
});
```

What I do wrong here? please help,

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to come down to the `ion-` prefix missing in several places.

When I change `nav-view` to `ion-nav-view`, `tabs` to `ion-tabs` etc, things seems to work.

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LemAVZxwPTH6MdpqWogd?p=preview)

Comment: thank you mate, you saved me time, didn't think about